# How to get Entry value to not be a string variable for Mysql query = Tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

The query seems to work but the 'Selected Entry' turns into a string of numbers which messes up my query.

```
def find_roster(n=""):
 global cursor
cursor.execute("""SELECT num, firstname, surname, assign FROM active WHERE num='%s'"""%(n))
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for results in rows:
    rosterList.insert("end", results)
cursor.close()
print(n)
print(rows)
return rows

numLabel=Label(root, text="Employee #")
numLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)

findButt=Button(root, text="Find", width=12, command=find_roster)
findButt.grid(row=1, column=5)


num_input=StringVar()
num_input=Entry(root,textvariable=num_input)
num_input.grid(row=0,column=1)

-----


findButt=Button(root, text="Find", width=12, command=lambda: find_roster(num_input))
findButt.grid(row=1, column=5)
```

CONSOLE PRINT RESULT

```
.140526443864584
```

()   #QUERY RESULT

NEEDS TO BE

```
1-214

(1-214, JOE,HOEY,OFF)   #QUERY RESULT
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:

```
num_input=StringVar()
num_input=Entry(root,textvariable=num_input)
```

which is very much the same thing as:

```
a = 3
a = -4
```

but further add:

```
a = 3
a = -4
print(a)
```

What do you think this will print?

---

Replace:

```
num_input=StringVar()
num_input=Entry(root,textvariable=num_input)
```

with:

```
anything_but = StringVar()
num_input = Entry(root, textvariable=anything_but)
```

as you're later on assigning an entire `Entry` widget as `num_input` so it gets overwritten. Also to get its content as a string you have to use `get` method:

```
findButt=Button(root, text="Find", width=12,
                   command=lambda arg=anything_but.get(): find_roster(arg))
```

Comment: Sorry Nae, but I am really confused here - if I change to 'anything_but=' the textvariable errors as it is num_input.

Comment: @Raymond you need to change that too. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ok so now there are no errors, however I get an empty query and () result

Comment: @Raymond Sure. But I can't keep guessing your errors. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47985807/how-to-get-entry-value-to-not-be-a-string-variable-for-mysql-query-tkinter/47985841?noredirect=1#comment82940581_47985807).

Comment: There are no errors just the console print showing blank for 'print (n)' and () for 'print rows'.  So it appears the request is blank so the query result is blank.

Comment: @Raymond Make sure your entry is actually not blank then? With either manually entering, or `num_input.insert('0', 'this is what's inside entry')`.

Comment: That works and results with a sql query. So why is my text input showing as blank??? Though the entry box shows my text?

Comment: In fact of I type over the INSERT with a different query text - the insert overrides....

Comment: But it must be, because the 'insert' works against the find_roster def.  Listen Im lost here, but the code appears to be working short of my input variable, though I have inputted text - it's just not being applied.

Comment: Im at a loss here

Comment: @Raymond I'm sorry but it's unlikely that I can help you further without you updating the code based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47985807/how-to-get-entry-value-to-not-be-a-string-variable-for-mysql-query-tkinter/47985841?noredirect=1#comment82940581_47985807).

Comment: I did matched your code and why I am seeing better results and the insert syntax works perfectly. Even spacing matches

Comment: For what every reason anything_but = StringVar() is not working as far as passing on what I type as a  textvariable

Comment: def find_roster(n):
    n=anything_but.get()  FIXED IT